# I'm trying to plot a chart with the 50EMA and 100EMA. everything shows but for some reason I don't see the EMA lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, ta-lib

This is what my code looks like so far. is it because I'm on the M1 timeframe? but for no reason I cant see the 50 and 100EMA

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplfinance as mpf
from datetime import datetime
import talib as tb





close_price.set_index("time", inplace=True)
ema = stream.EMA(close_price["close"], timeperiod=50)

close_price['EMA_50'] = ema
mpf.plot(close_price, type='candle', style='yahoo', ylabel='Price', mav=(50, 100))
```

[image]

Comment: Since no data is presented, I don't know the details of the data frame, but it cannot be drawn with just the closing price. without using talib, the following code will produce a candlestick graph that includes moving averages. `import yfinance as yf;data = yf.download("AAPL", start="2022-01-01", end="2023-01-01");mpf.plot(data, type='candle', style='yahoo', ylabel='Price', mav=(50, 100))`

Comment: Since your data is in a dataframe called `close_price`, then I suggest, in order to enable others to see what your dataframe looks like and thereby possibly answer your questions, I suggest ***just before calling `mpf.plot()`,*** do **`close_price.to_csv('filename.csv')`.**  Then post `filename.csv` somewhere public where others can access the data, and will be able to restore it via `pd._read_csv()`.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the data, based on the appearance of your plot I can make the following assumptions:

- The data is minute by minute data
- The plot shows *only* 10 minutes of data.
- In the call to `mpf.plot()` you have asked for a 50 point, and a 100 point moving average.

For a 50-period moving average, you will need to plot at least 52
points (52 minutes worth of data) to see at least a 2-point line
representing the 50-point-moving-average.  For a 100 period moving
average, you will need to plot at least 102 points (102 minutes
worth) to see a 2-point line representing a 100-point-moving-average.

Bottom line:  You will need to either plot a lot more data, or use smaller moving averages, or both, to be able to see anything.

---

P.S.

You mention in your question that you want the EMA (Exponential Moving Average), but when calling `mpf.plot()` you are using the `mav=(50,100)` kwarg which is simple moving average.
**To get exponential moving average the kwarg would be `ema=(50,100)`.**

Note, however, in the case of EMA, because of the way the Pandas `ewm()` function works, *unlike SMA* (`mav`), you actually ***can*** plot a 50 point EMA with fewer than 50 data points, ***but you should be aware*** that until you have reached at least 50 data points then the calculated EMA is ***not*** a true 50-period EMA, but rather an approximation using fewer that 50 data points.